# ADFS 3.0 Custom attribute store configuration error

Tags: adfs

I am trying to configure custom attribute store on my dev ADFS server. I have created sample solution to inject custom claims to ADFS. Added the custom DLL to the adfs server (C:\Windows\ADFS). Created custom attribute store in ADFS management console. When I check event log to see if the custom attribute store is loaded successfully, I see below error.

> server: windows server 2012 r2
>
> (Solution namespace: ADFSCustomAtrStore --- Dll name:
>   ADFSCustomAtrStore.dll)

I have tried below two options for custom attribute classname:

> ADFSCustomAtrStore.Class1, ADFSCustomAtrStore
>   ADFSCustomAtrStore.Class1
>
> EVENT ID: 149
>
> During processing of the Federation Service configuration, the
>   attribute store 'ADFSCustomAtrStore' could not be loaded.   Attribute
>   store type: ADFSCustomAtrStore.Class1
>
> User Action  If you are using a custom attribute store, verify that
>   the custom attribute store is configured using AD FS Management
>   snap-in.
>
> Additional Data  Could not load type 'ADFSCustomAtrStore.Class1' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy, Version=6.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

To fix the issue tried below, but no success. 
Installed custom solution to GAC. And provided below in custom attribute store class text box in ADFS:

```
CustomAttributeStores.Class1,AttributeStore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[SolKEY].
```

Any inputs/help would be great.

I have referred below blog post to configure custom attribute store:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/cloudpfe/archive/2013/12/27/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-store-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same post and I just put the attribute store dll in the c:\windows\adfs. In my visual studio 2013 project I grabbed the Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.dll from the ADFS server.
Red carefully to all event messages generally the answer in the event ID 111 following the event ID 364.
What I learned is : parameters are case sensitive.